# Reset to a custom previous point in the code JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, css, loops, menu, responsive

I am building a responsive mobile menu. I am a beginner so don't know how to use loops effectively.

The Problem is that When in mobile view, hamburger menu icon shows and when it is clicked, it changes to close menu icon & when clicked again, changes to hamburger menu.
BUT it stucks there. it only works to 2 clicks and after that it stuck to hamburger menu icon & never changes to close menu icon.

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function detectWidth(){

    let screenWidth = screen.width;
    
    if(screenWidth <= 800){
    
        document.querySelector("nav ul").innerHTML = `<img id="menuIcon" src="Header/menuIcon.png" alt="Menu Icon">`;
        
        // TO SHOW MENU ITEMS & CLOSE MENU ICON AFTER CLICKING ON HAMBURGER MENU BUTTON
        document.querySelector("#menuIcon").addEventListener("click", function(){
            document.querySelector("#menuIcon").outerHTML = `<img id="closMenuIcon" src="Header/closeMenuIcon.png" alt="Close Menu Icon">`;
            

            //TO CHANGE BACK TO MENU ICON
            document.querySelector("#closMenuIcon").addEventListener("click", function () {
                    document.querySelector("#closMenuIcon").outerHTML = `<img id="menuIcon" src="Header/menuIcon.png" alt="Menu Icon">`;
            });
        })
    
    } else{
    
        document.querySelector("nav ul").innerHTML = `<ul>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                                                        </ul>`;
    }
});
```

please forgive me if it is so obvious, I am a beginner and i think it requires loop of some kind.

Comment: The stopPropagation() method of the Event interface prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases. It does not, however, prevent any default behaviors from occurring; for instance, clicks on links are still processed. If you want to stop those behaviors, see the preventDefault() method. Direct from Mozilla

Comment: Check out https://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/Atyop. It uses css and changing the icon by adding removing class name

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply apply burger to `.burger` class and close to `.close-menu` and then you can just toggle class with javascript. That'd be much more easier and readable.

Comment: Also, you can achieve responsiveness using css. Learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I really don't know how it works but yeah, at least it works now.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function detectWidth(){

    let screenWidth = screen.width;
    
    if(screenWidth <= 800){
    
        document.querySelector("nav ul").innerHTML = `<img id="menuIcon" src="Header/menuIcon.png" alt="Menu Icon">`;
        
        // TO SHOW MENU ITEMS & CLOSE MENU ICON AFTER CLICKING ON HAMBURGER MENU BUTTON
        function toggleMenu(){
            document.querySelector("#menuIcon").addEventListener("click", function(){
                document.querySelector("#menuIcon").outerHTML = `<img id="closMenuIcon" src="Header/closeMenuIcon.png" alt="Close Menu Icon">`;
                
    
                //TO CHANGE BACK TO MENU ICON
                document.querySelector("#closMenuIcon").addEventListener("click", function () {
                        document.querySelector("#closMenuIcon").outerHTML = `<img id="menuIcon" src="Header/menuIcon.png" alt="Menu Icon">`;
                        toggleMenu();
                });               
            })
        }
        toggleMenu();
        
    
    } else{
    
        document.querySelector("nav ul").innerHTML = `<ul>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                                                        </ul>`;
    }
});
```

Comment: it works fine for the reason I've wrote below. Now, when you fire `toggleMenu()` it doesn't really care whether element was changed or not, because It looks for the element again, using query.

Answer (score 1):

Even though It's better to use toggling css className, I want to point out on the problem in this case. In your case scenario, you apply event on button element but the thing is `outerHTML` [replaces the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) so all events get fired. If you want to stick out to your method, you need to redeclare the events one more time.